# Tracking failed org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 06280119 api/solr/aclchangesets return status:404

Tags: alfresco-share

we have installing alfresco 5.1 version.we have followed the below steps as per docs for Generating Secure Keys for Solr 4 Communication.We have different servers for Solr application and different server for Alfresco application.as per docs ,we have configued all config files in the shared servers and solr servers.

http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/solr4-install-config.html

2016-07-28 07:52:30,008 ERROR [solr.tracker.AbstractTracker] [SolrTrackerScheduler_Worker-22] Tracking failed 
    org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 06280119 api/solr/aclchangesets return status:404 
    at org.alfresco.solr.client.SOLRAPIClient.getAclChangeSets(SOLRAPIClient.java:169) 
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AclTracker.checkRepoAndIndexConsistency(AclTracker.java:342) 
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AclTracker.trackRepository(AclTracker.java:320) 
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AclTracker.doTrack(AclTracker.java:111) 
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AbstractTracker.track(AbstractTracker.java:192) 
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.TrackerJob.execute(TrackerJob.java:54) 
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216) 
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:563) 
    2016-07-28 07:52:30,008 ERROR [solr.tracker.AbstractTracker] [SolrTrackerScheduler_Worker-30] Model tracking failed 
    org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 06280122 GetModelsDiff return status is 404 
    at org.alfresco.solr.client.SOLRAPIClient.getModelsDiff(SOLRAPIClient.java:1164) 
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.trackModelsImpl(ModelTracker.java:256) 
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.trackModels(ModelTracker.java:214) 
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.ensureFirstModelSync(ModelTracker.java:236) 
    at org.alfresco.solr.component.EnsureModelsComponent.prepare(EnsureModelsComponent.java:87) 
    at org.apache.solr.handler.component.AlfrescoSearchHandler.handleRequestBody(AlfrescoSearchHandler.java:290) 
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135) 
    at org.alfresco.solr.Cloud.getResponse(Cloud.java:166) 
    at org.alfresco.solr.Cloud.getSolrDocumentList(Cloud.java:150) 
    at org.alfresco.solr.SolrInformationServer.getDocsWithUncleanContent(SolrInformationServer.java:722) 
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ContentTracker.doTrack(ContentTracker.java:81) 
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AbstractTracker.track(AbstractTracker.java:192) 
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.TrackerJob.execute(TrackerJob.java:54) 
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216) 
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:563)

Comment: This is probably not the first error in your logs, try restarting your instance and update the error log with the first error you encounter !

Comment: this is first error i see in solr logs

Comment: You are probably mistaken

Comment: login page is coming for share but when i start solr serevr above error is coming.